# Vuejs build failed

Tags: vue.js, build, uglifyjs

I am trying to take a vuejs build and getting the following error. I tried all ways but failed. I am using Vue CLI 3

```
ERROR in build.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (MockStorage) [./node_modules/vuex-persist/dist/esm/index.js:6,0][build.js:26775,4]
```

Can someone help me to fix this ?

Comment: Nobody knows what the **name** token could be. This build error seems to be specific to your code and / or setup. You’ll need to provide more information so people can understand the problem, and HELP YOU solve it.

Comment: Its not specific to my code (See the file ./node_modules/vuex-persist/dist/esm/index.js) This is a common one and I had seen many solutions in the internet. Unfortunately; none of these works for me

Comment: Oh, OK! That’s why I wrote “/setup”. If you provide more information someone might be able to recognize your problem or even reproduce it. Please understand that nobody knows the dev / prod environment you’re working with, unless you describe it. Nobody knows what you have tried unless you write it down in your question (“everything” is a bit obscure). You’ve added that you use vuex-persist (so I guess you use vuex too).